# Why can't I add an entity with children on a new context via EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, firebird, ef-core-3.1

According to [How to add a parent record with its children records in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517584/how-to-add-a-parent-record-with-its-children-records-in-ef-core) the following should work:

**Model Builder**

```cs
mb.Entity<IdentifierTable>().HasKey("StockID");
mb.Entity<StockTable>().HasKey("StockID");
mb.Entity<ProductTable>().HasKey("IdentifierID");
mb.Entity<GroupsTable>().HasKey("GroupId");

mb.Entity<StockTable>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Identifier)
    .WithOne(y => y.Stock)
    .HasForeignKey<IdentifierTable>(y => y.StockID);

mb.Entity<StockTable>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Group)
    .WithMany(y => y.Stock)
    .HasForeignKey(y => y.GroupId);

mb.Entity<ProductTable>()
    .HasOne<IdentifierTable>(x => x.Identifier)
    .WithOne(y => y.Product)
    .HasForeignKey<IdentifierTable>(y => y.IdentifierID);

base.OnModelCreating(mb);
```

**Relevant parts of StockTable**

```cs
public int StockID { get; set; }
public int? GroupId { get; set; }
[...]
public IdentifierTable Identifier { get; set; }
public GroupsTable Group { get; set; }
```

**Relevant parts of IdentifierTable**

```cs
public int IdentifierID { get; set; }
public ProductTable Product { get; set; }
public int StockID { get; set; }
public StockTable Stock { get; set; }
```

**Relevant parts of ProductTable**

```cs
public int? IdentifierID { get; set; }
public IdentifierTable Identifier { get; set; }
[...]
```

**Relevant parts of GroupsTable**

```cs
public int GroupId { get; set; }
public List<StockTable> Stock { get; set; }
```

**The actual program**

```cs
foreach (var item in contexts.originalContext.StockTable
                     .Include(x=>x.Group)
                     .Include(x=>x.Identifier)
                     .ThenInclude(y=>y.Product))
{
        contexts.destinationContext.StockTable.Add(item);
        contexts.destinationContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, when saving the changes, I get an exception:

> violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EST_IDENT_PROD" on table
> "ProductTable" Foreign key reference target does not exist

I understood EF Core should add `StockTable`'s child properties as well (`IdentifierTable`, `ProductTable`, and distinct `GroupsTable`). What am I doing wrong here?

The reason I'm using FluentAPI is because I'm working with a pre-made database, I can't edit table/column names, nor relationships. Could it be because `IdentifierTable.StockID` is both primary key and foreign key?

I think I might have found a clue: Checking a tentative migration, I found EF Core is creating two foreign keys alright. However, it is creating both on `IdentifierTable`. The relationships I aim for are:

- One `StockTable` has one and only one `IdentifierTable`.
- One `IdentifierTable` has one or none `ProductTable`.
- One `StockTable` has one or none `GroupsTable`.
- One `GroupsTable` has none, one, or multiple `StockTable`.

I think I might not be able to use this database with EF Core. I tried scaffolding the models database-first, and EF Core didn't manage to understand a single foreign key relation.

Comment: It's a good idea to be consistent and avoid stringy typed, error prone code where possible. For example `mb.Entity<TB_EST_IDENTIFICADOR>().HasKey("ID_ESTOQUE")` can be `mb.Entity<TB_EST_IDENTIFICADOR>().HasKey(e => e.ID_ESTOQUE)`

Comment: Could you use english in your code please

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, Is it possible that the type parameter in your fluent statement for Product Table is not required? Since you are already stating that the ProductTable .HasOne x.Identifier ... try removing the parameter types from the statements

Comment: (Un)fortunately, we finally ditched the third-party database, and are now using our own.